# Codecademy - PHP - Objects in php (5/10)

Tags: php, object

I am doing PHP lessons in codecademy and i'm stuck near the end. 
I'd realy appreciate some help here. 
From my i got i think i did my tasks.
Here is how it is exactly said :

> The public properties $firstname, $lastname and $age should get a
>   value via a constructor. Change the code, so $teacher's: $firstname is
>   "boring", $lastname is "12345", $age is 12345 Add your $firstname,
>   $lastname and $age to $student. echo the $age of $student.

And i keep getting the messege:

> Oops, try again. Hey, did you forget add my name as a property to the object? :-P

```
<?php
        class Person {
            public $isAlive = true;
            public $firstname;
            public $lastname;
            public $age;

        // public function _contstruct    You can do it!

            public function __construct($firstname, $lastname, $age) {
                $this->firstname = $firstname;    
                $this->lastname = $lastname;
                $this->age = $age;
                }
        }
            $teacher = new Person("Boring","12345",12345);
            $student = new Person("Stud","Nenti",19);
            echo $teacher->isAlive;
            echo $student->age;
        ?>
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code that you've supplied above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you wrote is correct as far as I know.  However, it might just be an issue of case-sensitivity.

When a Codecademy lesson checks to see if you did it right, it runs a script that checks for variable values, console output, etc.  Sometimes, the checks are very picky about being exact.  It might be checking for `"boring"` (from the instructions) instead of `"Boring"` (what you wrote in your code).